# How do i choose which imputation itteration to use for my data after using pmm in R?

Tags: r, data-imputation

I have 40 continuous variables with missing data.

I imputed the missing data using predictive mean matching through the MICE package in R, I did 5 iterations for each imputation.

**My question is how do I choose which iteration to use for the whole dataset?**

I know that for each variable it should be as close as possible to the original mean,
however say I choose the 5th iteration for one variable- as I can see the new mean is the closest to the original mean- that same iteration may not be the best one to choose for the other 39 variables.

**So do I have to do separate imputations for each of the 40 variables on 40 separate datasets, export those datasets and then combine them all at the end?**

**Or is it safe to just choose any of the iterations and apply it to all 40 variables in one go?**

Note:
I can't pool the data into a model because this specific dataset only contains my dependent variables. (They are in a different format to my independent variables, so I need to first impute the data and then average each variable, input those averages into another dataset with the predictor variables, and then finally run a model with those averages and my predictor variables)

Answer (score 4):

Multiple imputation using the chained equation approach of `mice` imputes all variables in an imputation cycle.  When multiple variables are missing on the same observation you need to have some burn-in cycles to get past some of the arbitrariness of which variable was imputed first.  Current guidance on how many imputations to keep is one imputation for every 1% of observations that have at least one missing variable.  You don't pick and choose from among the imputations.  If you have m imputations you'll get m completed datasets, do m separate analyses, and combine the parameter estimates and standard errors using Rubin's rule. So you don't choose one imputation for one variable and another imputation for another, out of the m imputations.  Details are in the Missing Data chapter in [rms](https://hbiostat.org/rms).  This chapter also describes the `aregImpute` and `fit.mult.impute` functions in the R `Hmisc` package.  `aregImpute` uses predictive mean matching with chained equations but allows all effects to be nonlinear, unlike the linearity assumptions used in `mice`.

Comment: Hi Frank thank you for this detailed answer to my question. I have 30% of my total observations missing, would this require 30 cycles of imputation?

Comment: Yes, 30 imputed values for each missing value, i.e., 30 filled-in datasets, 30 analyses.

Comment: Okay thank you!